# How do I fix the following error: "Cannot read property 'init' of undefined"?

Tags: meteor, initialization, atmosphere.js

I am running Meteor release METEOR@1.4.2.3

I recently installed a social media share package via Atmosphere.

```
meteor add ellisonleao:sharerjs.
```

More information about the package can also be found at: 
http://www.ellison.rocks/sharer.js/

My template event handler looks like this:

```
Template.detail.events({

"click .sharer": function() {
//add new buttons with share behaviour

$('.postedImagesWell').append(<button class="sharer button" data-sharer="facebook" data-url="https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/">Share on Facebook</button>);                                             
window.Sharer.init();
    }
});
```

Find below the template in code:

```
<template name="detail">

<div class="postedImagesWell">
<img class = "img-responsive img-rounded postedImages" id = "trial" src="{{this.photo.url}}" alt="thumbnail" >

</template>
```

when I run click on the `Share on Facebook` link. I see this error message in my browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

Any help on how to resolve the issue would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait..when you click on an element with a class `sharer` you append a button with the same class to your div. But initially your template doesn't have any element with the class `sharer`. How does your listener gets called? Anyway.. the error means that the `Sharer` object isn't available on the global scope of the `window`. Maybe you should try the other repo listed on the atmosphere page of this lib: https://github.com/okmttdhr/sharer.npm.js

Comment: If that package does not work as well - just add sharer.js file into your Meteor apps head.html file in head, just like a regular JS plugin (which it is)

Comment: @fmilani Thanks. Just like you suggested I installed the other repo `npm install sharer.npm.js`. But help me out here, looking at the structure of my code, specifically the event handler function `"click .sharer": function() { ... }` how should I achieve the same share effect. Can you kindly demonstrate in code?

Comment: I haven't used blaze in a while...but you could do similar to what is in the repo example. First, I don't think you need to append the share button with jquery. Just add the button to your template, and on the click listener, instead of calling `window.Sharer`, you add the `event` parameter to the listener function then instantiate a new sharer with `const sharer = new Sharer(event.target); sharer.share()`. And you would need to import the Sharer so you can instatiate it: you would import the sharer with `import Sharer from 'sharer.npm.js';`

Comment: @fmilani You are a life saver! Thank you, your suggestion worked. Though I've spent/wasted allot of time trying to get this package to work, I have to give credit to the author because its one of the best social media/network share packages out there. Hence me really spending time to get it to work. Thanks once again.

Comment: Glad I helped! I will post the comment as an answer to also help others that may come across this problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the other repo listed on the atmosphere page of this lib: https://github.com/okmttdhr/sharer.npm.js

Also, I don't think you need to append the share button with jquery. Just add the button to your template, and on the click listener, instead of calling `window.Sharer`, you add the `event` parameter to the listener function then instantiate a new sharer, like this:

```
import Sharer from 'sharer.npm.js';
// ...

Template.detail.events({

  "click .sharer": function(event) {
     const sharer = new Sharer(event.target);
     sharer.share();
  }
});
```